# Mimetype (using Google Script) for Google Doc Creation Working in Some Instances and Not Others

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types

I am trying to create a new spreadsheet in Google Drive using Google Script.  When using the code below the Mimetypes work in some instances (like OPENDOCUMENT_SPREADSHEET and JAVASCRIPT) but not in others (like GOOGLE_DRAWINGS and GOOGLE_SHEETS).  Can someone explain the reason for this?

```
function createSheet() {
  var mimeTest = MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_SPREADSHEET;
  var quickReferenceSheet = DriveApp.createFile("test", "", mimeTest);
}
```

Error message comes up as "Invalid argument: file.contentType (line 3, file "Sheet Formula Check")"

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to create new Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Unfortunately, Google Docs cannot be created using `DriveApp.createFile()`. I think that this might be the specification. So how about using the create method of Class SpreadsheetApp?

#### Sample script 1:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("test");
```

#### Sample script 2:

If you want to create new Spreadsheet using Drive API, how about this sample script? When you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services.

```
var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "test", parents: [{id: "### folderId ###"}]});
```

- When Drive API is used, the new Spreadsheet can be directly created in the specific folder. This cannot be done by the create method of Class SpreadsheetApp.

#### References:

- [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname)
- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The second one does what I need.  It is just odd that it would be in the documentation and only work sometimes.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename-content-mimetype

Comment: @Joe M. Thank you for replying. The 2nd one is not ``DriveApp.createFile()``. And it cannot be used for creating Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document, Slides, Drawing and so on). So I proposed to use Drive API or SpreadsheetApp Service. If my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Google Drive treats Google Docs files (sheets, presentation, etc) very differently from binary files. AppScript is a user-friendly abstraction over the latter. If you want control over the former, you will need to use the Advanced Drive service at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive, but note that this assumes a more detailed level of understanding about Drive concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the second approach given by @Tanaike based on `Drive.Files.insert`: for inserting into a shared drive, the `supportsAllDrives` parameter is necessary.

I've tested this for both `GOOGLE_SHEETS` and `GOOGLE_DOCS` mimetypes, hopefully it works for other types too:

```
    var resource = {};
    resource.title = filename;
    resource.mimeType = mimetype;
    resource.parents = [{id: folderId}];

    var newFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource,undefined,{supportsAllDrives: true});
```

The second argument is `blob`, and setting it to `undefined` creates an empty file in the specified folder.